# Mapa não carrega, apresentando erro

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Estou começando a desenvolver em Android, só que me deparei com um problema para gerar um mapa simples, já vi e revi a documentação da Google Developer e outros tutoriais da internet que mostram como é fácil fazer uma aplicação deste tipo. Meu código:

Arquivo AndroidManifest:

`

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission android:name="br.com.engandtec.locationmaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="br.com.engandtec.locationmaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyD-FWEwQsLHfJJWIyQc-TxALIGju-iMgvU"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
         />  

    <activity
        android:name="br.com.engandtec.locationmaps.MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

`

arquivo: activity_map

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MapActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

 <fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

e o arquivo: MapActivity

```
package br.com.engandtec.locationmaps;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MapActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

quando instancio o aap aparace a seguinte tela
[image]

e ao clicar no botão atualizar aparece mensagem que o app parou e no LogCat mostra estas linhas 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image]

Comment: Poderia informar o link do tutorial e nos mostrar o erro em forma de texto ao invés de imagem?

Comment: @Math: O SO reduziu o tamanho da imagem para caber no layout mas você pode baixar a imagem à parte e ela estará no tamanho normal, com o texto visível.

Comment: @Piovezan eu sei, mas não seria mais fácil se estivesse em texto?

Comment: Você tentou rodar em um dispositivo real ao invés do emulador?

Answer (score 1):

Você não vai conseguir utilizar o mapa no emulador do Android a não ser que passe por um processo complexo de modificação do emulador (o que não vale a pena).

O melhor a fazer é usar um emulador de terceiros. Eu utilizo o [Genymotion](http://www.gujavasc.org/2013/09/genymotion.html).

Além disso, ele sobe e roda infinitas vezes mais rápido do que o emulador padrão do Android.

Outras informações [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154222/google-play-on-android-4-0-emulator/16973600#16973600).

Answer (score 0):

Essa exception provavelmente significa que você não tem o aplicativo `Google Play Services` instalado. Baixe-o do Google Play (usando o aplicativo `Play Store`), execute novamente seu projeto e veja se o erro vai embora.

Comment: É possível baixar o Google Play pelo Play Store? Realmente não sei, estou curioso.

Comment: @Math: No caso me refiro ao aplicativo Google Play Services. Acho que você está se referindo ao aplicativo Play Store, correto? Nunca tentei baixá-lo, porque ele já vem instalado no Android até onde sei.

Comment: @Math Complementando, [aqui](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/190860?hl=en) afirma-se que não é possível baixá-lo.

Comment: Sim, estava me referindo ao app. Que seja, dá pra baixar o services então? Talvez a solução dele é só clicar naquele botão de atualizar, rs..

Comment: @Math: Clicar no botão atualizar é que causa a exception. :)

Comment: Ah tá! To precisando ler com mais calma, rs..

Answer (score 0):

Quando você baixa o sdk, o Google Play services está lá.

Você pode verificar se ele está instalado clicando no botão Android SDK Manager (aquele botão que fica na barra que tem um Android com uma seta para baixo).

Uma vez aberto o SDK Manager, vai em Extras e verifique se está instalado o Google Play Services. Caso não esteja, marque e clique em Install 1 package.

Depois que instalar, importe a biblioteca do Google Play services para o seu eclipse.

Import > Android > Existing Android Code Into Workspace > Root Directory (Browse) > Navega onde você instalou android-sdks > extras > google > google_play_services > libproject > google-play-services_lib > Clica open.

Depois disso, vai no seu projeto, clica com segundo botão e depois em Properties > Android > Library > Add > e selecione a do google_play_services.

Dê um Clean e Build e deve dá certo.

Comment: o google_play_services já esta baixado e tbm está na lib do projeto!

Comment: Certo, então dá uma olhada nos samples que existem na mesma pasta que contém essa lib.

Mas já de antemão. Já que você tá usando um fragment, seria melhor usar uma FragmentActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta essas alterações. Você tem de instanciar o mapa.

```
    public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        private GoogleMap mMap;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
            setUpMapIfNeeded();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            setUpMapIfNeeded();
        }

        private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
            if (mMap == null) {
                mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                        .getMap();
                if (mMap != null) {
                    setUpMap();
                }
            }
        }

        private void setUpMap() {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está com problema na hora de criar o seu Intent, pois o erro que você postou é que não tem nenhuma activity que está respondendo pelo seu Intent, isso não tem a ver com o Maps.